# How keep only duplicate lines?

Tags: text-editing, filtering

Emacs 26.1. Windows 10

In buffer I has text like this:

```
    3333333
    1111111
    $PAC_LTC
    1337_BTC
    1337_LTC
    404_BTC
    42_BTC
    222222
    42_LTC
    808_ETH
    8BIT_BTC
    8BIT_BTC
    8BIT_BTC
    8BIT_DOGE
    8BIT_ETH
    8BIT_LTC
    ACC_DOGE
    ACC_USDT
    ACC_USDT
    ADC_DOGE
    ADC_DOGE
    ADC_DOGE
    ADC_ETH
    ADC_USDT
    8BIT_USDT
    8BIT_USDT
    42_ETH
```

I need to keep only duplicate lines. 
The result must be like this:

```
8BIT_BTC
8BIT_BTC
8BIT_BTC
8BIT_USDT
8BIT_USDT
ACC_USDT
ACC_USDT
ADC_DOGE
ADC_DOGE
ADC_DOGE
```

P.S. I try by this command: `delete-non-matching-lines`

[image]

But after press `Enter` whole text delete from buffer.

Comment: All repeated lines in your example are consecutive. Is that always the case? (In that case one can skip the sorting.) Does the order of the lines matter?

Comment: No. It's not always the case. Lines can be not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a command that finds all duplicate lines in the buffer and deletes the rest:

```el
(defun keep-duplicate-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (let (lines dups)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (when (/= (char-after (1- (point-max))) ?\n)
        (newline))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (forward-line 1)
        (push (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position)
                                              (line-end-position))
              lines))
      (dolist (line lines)
        (when (and (> (cl-count line lines :test 'equal) 1)
              (not (string= "" line)))
          (push (regexp-quote line) dups)))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (keep-lines (mapconcat #'identity
                  dups
                  "\\|")))))
```

Comment: I get error: Symbol’s function definition is void: count

Comment: @jagrg You should use `cl-count` instead of `count`. `cl-count` is autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer addresses the **original version** of the question **"How keep only duplicate lines?"**. It shows the duplicates in an auxiliary buffer and keeps the original buffer unmodified.

1. Copy the whole buffer with <kbd>C-x h M-w</kbd>.
2. Create a new buffer with <kbd>C-x b</kbd> `*work*` <kbd>RET</kbd>. (Replace `*work*` with a buffer name to your likings.)
3. Yank the text there with <kbd>C-y</kbd>
4. Mark the whole buffer `*work*` by <kbd>C-x h</kbd> and sort its lines with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sort-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd>
5. Mark the whole buffer by <kbd>C-x h</kbd> and delete all lines that do not occur multiple times in sequence with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `delete-non-matching-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^\(.*\)\(` <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> `\1$\)+` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Note: The sequence <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> inserts a verbatim newline in the minibuffer.
Only the gray sections `^\(.*\)\(` and `\1$\)+` are intended for copy-paste. You must type the part <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> in the middle of the regexp as key sequence with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button pressed.

---

If you want to modify the buffer such that you only **keep the replicated lines** you can skip steps 1, 2, and 3. Furthermore, use the original buffer instead of `*work*` in step 4. I.e.:

1. Mark the whole buffer by <kbd>C-x h</kbd> and sort its lines with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sort-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Mark the whole buffer by <kbd>C-x h</kbd> and delete all lines that do not occur multiple times in sequence with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `delete-non-matching-lines` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^\(.*\)\(` <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> `\1$\)+` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: @Alexei It should work. I have tested it. Make sure to sort before applying `delete-non-matching-lines`. Be careful when typing the regexp (note that you cannot copy-paste but must type at least the `C-q C-j`). Please try again.

Comment: @Alexei You may not copy-paste the regexp as is but you must type `C-q C-j` as key sequence with `C-` standing for the pressed control key. Only the two gray sections `^\(.*\)\(` and `\1$\)+` of the regexp are intended for copy paste.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's work. I was copy paste C-q C-j. But I MUST input C-q C-j

Comment: @Alexei Yes, you need to use the key sequence `C-q C-j`. I modified my answer to state that more clear. Please remove the note about the non-working answer from your question